# Convert decimals to date

Tags: excel

The problem I am encountering is that some of the decimals numbers have turned into date format. For instance the value 46784 should be `2.28`, or value 32599 be `4.90`. I have already tried the "format cells" option --> text. What I am trying to achieve is to prevent this converting, I want the raw value.

As the shown in the picture, the problem is marked with red line:

[image]

Comment: @MacroMan - 46784 does come as 01-Feb-2028 but 32599 is 01-Apr-1989, not 01-Apr-1990.

Comment: Format the cells (Ctrl+1, Number, Custom) as `mm.yy`. However, that does not explain whether your other values are correct.

Comment: @Jeeped yeah, I only checked 4.90 - I realised just as you posted this! :$

Comment: Is this an import from a csv file by any chance?  The reason I ask is that excel may be converting something like 10.12 to Day and Month, which is why some have converted, and all the ones that havent are not valid day/months.

Comment: @bushell, the values are from another file. I solved this problem my copy-paste the values from source file to notepad, then from notepad to excel.